# vscode runOnSave - debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the [Emeralwalk runOnSave plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave) for VS Code but it's not working. How can I debug/troubleshoot it?

I have the JSON shown below in my settings.json. When I save a file, there is a message at the bottom of VS Code that reads, "Run on Save done.". Unfortunatly, the tile im attempting to touch is not there.  How can I debug run on save?

```
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "match": ".*",
                "cmd": "touch ~/______TEST_FILE______"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. open the **OUTPUT** panel `Ctrl + Shift + U`. (`cmd + shift + U` on macos)
2. Select the **OUTPUT** tab
3. In the dropdown near the top right of the panel, select `Run On Save`

Now the output of run on save will be displayed in this panel.